# get spark stage total number when application starts

Tags: apache-spark, listener, stage

I want to calculate rate of process on Spark .Using Spark Listener,running stage id can be acquired . But how can I acquire total number of stages the application  contains.Should I make it    manually? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by counting how many `StageInfo`s you get from the `org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerJobStart` event listener class.

You'll have to register the event listener for `onJobStart` events (found in this [doc](https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/SparkListenerInterface/#onjobstart)).

I found it more useful to count the total number of tasks and increment the total amount of tasks completed every time a task completed:

```
package com.xxx.xxx

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import com.codahale.metrics.{Counter, MetricRegistry, ScheduledReporter}
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.{SparkListener, SparkListenerJobStart, SparkListenerTaskEnd}

class BatchProgressListener(conf: MonitorConfig, topic: String) extends SparkListener {

  // Irrelevant code omitted
  ...
    
  override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd): Unit = {
    tasksCompleteCounter.inc()
  }

  override def onJobStart(jobStart: SparkListenerJobStart): Unit = {
    val sumOfTasks = jobStart.stageInfos.foldLeft(0L) { (acc, i) => acc + i.numTasks }
    totalTasksCounter.inc(sumOfTasks)
  }
}
```